# Service fabric on premise minimum nodes for stateless services

Tags: service-fabric-stateless

I have seen Microsoft documentation on the minimum 5 node clusters for production. I have only stateless services, and since there is no data does it have to be 5, can it not be 3?

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer. Because the naming service and and fail-over manager service are stateful, we need minimum 5.
Explained here.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-common-questions